# Novocaine - How to loop file playback? (iOS)

Tags: ios, core-audio

I'm using Novocaine by alexbw [Novocaine](https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine) for my audio project.

I'm playing around with the example code here for file reading.
The file plays back with no problem. I would like to loop this recording with the gap between the loops - any suggestion as to how I can do so?

Thanks.

Pier.

```
// AUDIO FILE READING OHHH YEAHHHH
// ========================================

NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                           @"testrecording.wav",
                           nil];
NSURL *inputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];
NSLog(@"URL: %@", inputFileURL);

fileReader = [[AudioFileReader alloc]
              initWithAudioFileURL:inputFileURL
              samplingRate:audioManager.samplingRate
              numChannels:audioManager.numOutputChannels];

[fileReader play];
[fileReader setCurrentTime:0.0]; 
//float duration = fileReader.getDuration;

[audioManager setOutputBlock:^(float *data, UInt32 numFrames, UInt32 numChannels)
 {
     [fileReader retrieveFreshAudio:data numFrames:numFrames numChannels:numChannels];         
     NSLog(@"Time: %f", [fileReader getCurrentTime]);

 }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
[audioManager setOutputBlock:^(float *data, UInt32 numFrames, UInt32 numChannels)
 {
     if( ![fileReader playing] ){

//      [fileReader release]; // for some reason this is causing an error, but I assume if you don´t do it, it will eventually cause a memory problem
//      fileReader = nil;

        [self playSound];
     } else {
         [fileReader retrieveFreshAudio:data numFrames:numFrames numChannels:numChannels];         
         NSLog(@"Time: %f", [fileReader getCurrentTime]);
    }
 }];

- (void) playSound
{
    NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                           @"testrecording.wav",
                           nil];
    NSURL *inputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];
    NSLog(@"URL: %@", inputFileURL);

    fileReader = [[AudioFileReader alloc]
                  initWithAudioFileURL:inputFileURL
                  samplingRate:audioManager.samplingRate
                  numChannels:audioManager.numOutputChannels];

    [fileReader play];
    [fileReader setCurrentTime:0.0]; 
    //float duration = fileReader.getDuration;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also modify the AudioFileReader.mm like this:

```
if ((self.currentFileTime - self.duration) < 0.01 && framesRead == 0) {
    [self setCurrentTime:0.0];
}
```

found in:

```
- (void)bufferNewAudio
```

This will result in a looping filereader without the need to re-init it.

Downside is, that you have to modify one of the frameworks files...

Hope it helps!