# Programmatic gapless audio sequence in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, audio, playback

I have a number of loops which have to be played seemlessly, in a way that I will only know which one to play when the last one finishes.

So I did it with AVAudioPlayer, added a delegate so I know when the audio finished playback, and in that method I triggered the next audio to be played, but there´s a silence gap between the two audio, and I cannot work with that.

I tried using .CAF format instead of .AIF but it was no good.

Can anyone help me with this? Core Audio seems a little bit difficult for me to understand right now.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code. Have you used `[myPlayer prepareToPlay];`? Have you tried pre loading the next item in the queue before the previous stops?

Comment: Yes I did tried prepareToPlay and I saved one player for each sound and stored them in a dictionary :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found Novocaine on github and tweaked it a little:

https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine

[Novocaine - How to loop file playback? (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189251/novocaine-how-to-loop-file-playback-ios/13785092#13785092)

Comment: Could you please share the tweak so it will be useful for all?

Comment: The tweak is on the second link as an answer for another post.